# Combining active and passive federation

Tags: silverlight, wif

Is it possible in WIF to combine active and passive federation? We currently have multiple Silverlight clients that communicate with 1 or more WCF services. The problem is that some of these services are hosted on a different domain. This means that, when we are using passive federation, calls to those services will fail when the user is not yet logged in for that domain (WIF will try to redirect the call). So is it possible to use passive federation when logging in to the website/Silverlight client and active federation when communicating with services? And has anyone done this (with Silverlight...)?

Comment: Do you have one or more STS's?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario sounds like this: You have a website that authenticates the user using passive federation to obtain a token. You hold on to the issued token, and pass it down into your silverlight client. The silverlight client uses that token to do active federation with your backend WCF services.

The most common way I've seen to achieve this is through RIA services. I've found [this article](http://hashtagfail.com/post/5441929717/ria-services-active-federation) which provides a nice introduction to this. Also, the [identity developer training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14347) has an end to end sample. Look for the one titled "Developing Identity-Driven Silverlight Applications".

Answer (score 0):

You say that WIF will redirect you WCF service call.  This seems to be exactly the same problem as in this StackOverflow question: [Passing SAML Token to WCF service from Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9882283/223837), and therefore [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883946/223837) might apply to your situation as well.